# How to disable IntelliSense in VS Code for Markdown?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

I don't want word completion for Markdown files in Visual Studio Code, how do I disable it? Ideally, for Markdown only but in the worst case, even a global switch would be good.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

IntelliSense suggestions in VS Code can be configured [globally or per each workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings) and as of [1.9 per file-type (language)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace#_language-specific-editor-settings), using the `editor.quickSuggestions`, `editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter` and `editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters` [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace).

```
// Controls if quick suggestions should show up or not while typing
"editor.quickSuggestions": true,
```

Since VSCode [1.11](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_11#_intellisense-in-comments), the `quickSuggestions` setting allows more fine-grained control over quick suggestions. However, this setting [accepts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/monaco.d.ts#L3393) either a boolean, or an object matching `IQuickSuggestionsOptions`, and defaults to `true`. Setting it to `false` disables quick suggestions all together.

**File-type settings** (preferred, as of 1.9 release)

Open the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_command-palette) by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> and run the `Configure language specific settings` command, then select `Markdown`.
A new editor pane will open where you can place those settings:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
  }
}
```

This way, you'll disable IntelliSense for markdown files only.

**Global**

Open [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_command-palette) by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, type `open user settings` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. A new editor pane will open where you can place those settings:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
}
```

**Workspace**

[Workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings) allows setting custom settings without applying them to your other VS Code projects. The workspace settings file is located under the `.vscode` folder in your project.

Open [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_command-palette) by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, type `open workspace settings` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. A new editor pane will open when you can place the same snipped as listed above.

I don't know if it's currently possible to associate settings with selected filetypes.

**Other options to configure**

In addition to `editor.quickSuggestions` several other options can be changed to further customize how IntelliSense works:

```
// Controls if quick suggestions should show up while typing
"editor.quickSuggestions": false,

// Controls if suggestions should be accepted with "Enter" - in addition to "Tab". Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines and accepting suggestions.
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": false,

// Controls the delay in ms after which quick suggestions will show up.
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,

// Enable word based suggestions
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,

// Controls if the editor should automatically close brackets after opening them
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,

// Controls if suggestions should automatically show up when typing trigger characters
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false
```

Comment: sadly, plain text `.txt` isn't deemed a language, to explicitly turn off autocomplete for...

Comment: for those looking to disable intellisense for `.txt` files like I was, this worked for me:
`"[plaintext]": {
  "editor.quickSuggestions": false
}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Was looking exactly for this. auto suggestions were so annoying and disturbing in markdown.

Comment: `editor.wordBasedSuggestions` is the one you'll want to turn off if you still want access to your Markdown extension intellisense but not have it cluttered by random words.

Comment: @Frank Nocke's comment is (now?) wrong, for `.txt` the type is Plain Text, see @MrDustpan's comment, thank you! You can do: 
    [Ctl-Shift-P] / 
    Configure Language Specific Settings... /
    [Enter] /
    Plain Text /
    [Enter] /
    `"editor.quickSuggestions": false` /
    [Ctl-S]

Comment: If you're trying to do this with `.mdx` files, beware that you will have to use `"[mdx]"` instead of `"[markdown]"`.

Comment: @FrankNocke Plain text is a language, it's called `PlainText` and it covers `.txt` files

Comment: Not sure when it was introduced, but at least in vsCode 1.74.3 the `editor.quickSuggestions` option is not a boolean anymore. Rather, it's a hash like `"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
}`

Answer (score 11):

In addition to what @JakubS said, there are two more settings that will help eliminate IntelliSense:

```
// Controls if the editor should automatically close brackets after opening them
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,

// Controls if suggestions should automatically show up when typing trigger characters
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
```

The `editor.autoClosingBrackets` option will stop Visual Studio Code from automatically inserting a closing parenthesis, bracket, brace, single quote, double quote, etc.

The `editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters` option will stop the auto-complete window from appearing when you type a dollar sign or dot.

All together, here's what I use:

```
// Controls if quick suggestions should show up while typing
"editor.quickSuggestions": false,

// Controls if suggestions should be accepted with "Enter" - in addition to "Tab". Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines and accepting suggestions.
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": false,

// Controls the delay in ms after which quick suggestions will show up.
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,

// Enable word based suggestions
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,

// Controls if the editor should automatically close brackets after opening them
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,

// Controls if suggestions should automatically show up when typing trigger characters
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false
```

Comment: I think the trigger characters may be language-specific. The dot is definitely a trigger character in Python and probably most if not all languages. But when I type the dollar sign (in Python), nothing happens, even if I have `"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": true`.

Answer (score 2):

This only worked for plaintext, not markdown. My settings.json is as below but I'm still getting suggestions in .md files (though now not in .txt files).

```
{
    "[markdown]": {
        "editor.quickSuggestions": false
    },
    "[plaintext]": {
        "editor.quickSuggestions": false
    },
    [other entries]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If also the markdown linting warnings are distracting and you want to disable them temporarily, you can use;

```
CTRL/COMMAND+SHIFT+P
Toggle linting by markdownlint on/off (temporarily)
```

You can enable it when you believe you're done with a document.