# How do I disable IntelliSense in comments in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code, mostly to work with PHP. Everytime I hit <kbd>.</kbd>, IntelliSense kicks in and offers me PHP globals and functions, starting with `$_COOKIE`. I usually know what global or function I want, so it's a bit annoying. This even happens when I'm within a comment block (`/* ... */` or `// ...`), which is far more annoying. Most of my time is spent going back and deleting `$_COOKIE`.

An example (not PHP,  but you get the idea):
[image: Sample animation from the official documentation]

I've tried disabling it [as suggested in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense):

```
// Controls if quick suggestions should show up while typing
"editor.quickSuggestions": false,

// Controls if suggestions should be accepted with "Enter" - in addition to "Tab". Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines and accepting suggestions.
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": true,

// Controls the delay in ms after which quick suggestions will show up.
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10000,

// Enable word based suggestions
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true
```

... but this has absolutely no effect whatsoever. I still get the list when I hit the dot. The delay increase from `100` to `1000`, too, has no effect.

1. How do I turn off IntelliSense inside code comments?
2. How do I disable IntelliSense on hitting <kbd>.</kbd> and just have it show up when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>? *(See update 2 below)*
3. <del>How do I disable IntelliSense completely, at least for PHP?</del>

*Update:* As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832753/how-to-disable-intellisense-in-vs-code-for-markdown?rq=1), disabling quick suggestions on trigger characters is achieved via:

```
// Controls if suggestions should automatically show up when typing trigger characters
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false
```

However, the other options mentioned above still don't do anything.

*Update 2:* It is [possible to mess with the <kbd>.</kbd> binding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_removing-a-specific-key-binding-rule) by adding this to the `keybindings.json` file:

```
{
    "key": ".",
    "command": "x",
}
```

However,this results in a warning message at the top of the screen that says "command 'x' not found". If you leave it empty or try to pass null to `command`, it still doesn't work, as it doesn't overwrite the default key binding. According to the documentation, it's possible to disable a certain action by prefixing it with a `-`, but this doesn't work for me:

```
"command": "-^acceptSelectedSuggestion"
```

or

```
"command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion"
```

In either case, `acceptSelectedSuggesdtion` isn't really the command that's being executed when I hit <kbd>.</kbd>, it's probably more like:

```
"command": "-editor.action.triggerSuggest"
```

But this doesn't work either.

Comment: See also https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1657 regarding the bug with intellisense in comments.

Sounds like a "won't fix", which is very sad. However it is a very itchy itch, and the IDE is open source, so surely someone at some point will scratch it with a patch!

Comment: It's almost 2018 and I'm still going back and deleting `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since about March or April 2017, this has been fixed, and also the default has changed to be no auto-complete in comments. The default is:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": true,
  "comments": false,
  "strings": false
},
```

I don't have that explicitly in my settings, and just did a test with a fresh PHP file, and I can type `global.` then space, and don't get anything auto-completed. (I tried both main code and in comments.)  I do see `$COOKIE` pop up as the first suggestion, but I need to use up/down arrows and then enter to bring it in.

Aha, `global.` then ENTER does give me `global.$COOKIE` (even in comments, which is a bit weird). I can fix that with:

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
```

To see other settings you might want to touch, go to the settings page and type "suggestion" in the search box. Each is commented. E.g. `"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,` gets rid of the auto-suggestions completely.

You can also specify the settings for just one language, e.g.

```
"[php]":  {
  "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
},
```

Answer (score 6):

Despite [Darren Cook's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46904929/95852) and the docs, the `editor.quickSuggestions` settings don't do anything *for suggestions that pop up due to trigger characters* (see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25109)). These seem to be subject to their own rules. Namely, when typing a trigger character in a string, you *never* get the suggestions, no matter what you said in `editor.quickSuggestions`; and when typing a trigger character in a comment or "other", you *always* get the suggestions, no matter what you said in `editor.quickSuggestions`.

Thus the only reliable way to get rid of what I'm calling "trigger-character suggestions" (which are by far the most annoying kind!) is to use the setting specifically devoted to it:

```
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false
```

If someone can leave a comment on how to discover what the trigger characters *are*, or better yet, how to specify them, I would be all too happy to edit my answer to take this into account.

Note that the suggestions which pop up due to actually matching the characters you type with known modules, variables, functions, etc., *are* still controlled by `editor.quickSuggestions` and *not* by `editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters`.

Comment: This is so annoying. When I type `*` in a doc comment in PHP, it suggests huge comments. Definitely turning this off.