# Disable comment with class name in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, javadoc, visual-studio-code

When I create a class like below:

[image]

Visual Studio Code adds the comment with Java class name above the class. How do I disable it? I mean I don't need this comment to be added at all.

[image]

Comment: You should not get rid of the comment, you should replace the classname with text to document your code. Even if the class at hand is a simple one, you can use `@see` constructs to guide readers.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46904929/10785239 answer by @Darren?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64688778/836330 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10565#issuecomment-721832613 if you want to disable snippets on a per-snippet basis.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume you have the [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) plugin installed. This seems to be the plugin that adds the `class` code snippet, I tried disabling it and the snippet no longer showed up.

A solution might be to write your own snippet with the `class` prefix that doesn't have the comment you dislike. I looked into user-created snippets in VSCode and found these useful support docs:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Here's how you accomplish this:

1. Open your command palette (`Ctrl` `Shift` `P` / `Cmd` `Shift` `P`) and search for `Preferences: Configure User Snippets`
2. Search for `java.json`
3. Add this JSON object to the file (within the existing brackets):

```
"Class": {
    "prefix": "class",
    "body": [
        "public class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE} {",
        "\t$0",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Public class"
}
```

You can change the `"prefix"` to anything you'd like. If you add this snippet, you'll see you now have 2 snippets when you enter the `class` keyword. I'm not really sure how to fix this, except for changing the prefix.

Another tip: you can change `"editor.snippetSuggestions"` to `"top"` in your settings. This will put snippets at the top of the suggestion box. (From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40129409/3235858)

I hope this helped you!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, it is the solution I want, however, that was helpful and I learnt how to create user snippets :)

Comment: @SomeDev No problem. Could you maybe clarify what solution you are looking for?

Comment: Go to: `File` | `Preferences` | `User Snippets` and choose the json file you want to modify

Comment: @rioV8 yes, that has the same effect as doing it through the command palette

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using some extension like Powershell. Go and disable or uninstall that extension and the problem will be automatically resolved.

Do check this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42901).

Thanks.

Comment: I have not installed Powershell

Comment: You are using some extension anything? .@SomeDev

Comment: I see no reason why other extensions enable this feature suddenly