# How can you identify which extension a snippet is configured under in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I'm writing some PowerShell scripts and typing '##' Automatically populates a bunch of multiline comment help scaffolding like this:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
#

.DESCRIPTION
Long description

.EXAMPLE
An example

.NOTES
General notes
#>
```

I do not want this behavior but I don't know where it's coming from.

I checked my user snippets in powershell.json but it's not something my idiot previous self did this time.

I went to the $HOME/.vscode/extensions folder but I have tons of extensions to sift through. Is there an easy way to identify where this snippet might be coming from so I can disable it more easily?

Comment: Are you merely typing `##` and it runs?  No `Tab` or simialr to trigger the snippet?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64688778/836330 you might be able to turn off that snippet suggestion by that technique.