# Visual studio code intellisense set to javascript lower version

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-community

I am using visual studio code 1.20.0

I am not sure when but after some updates vs code intellisense is giving ES6 output in every js file.

I am developing angularjs project & i simply don't want to use es6.

Currently i am getting below code using intellisense.

```
for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    const element = array[index];

}

array.forEach(element => {

});
```

I want it like it was before. Like below

```
for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {      
}

array.forEach(function(element) {

});
```

How can i set javascript to lower version. I have **not added any plugin** in my workspace.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link Bro...
IntelliSense suggestions in VS Code can be configured globally or per each workspace and as of 1.9 per file-type (language), using the editor.quickSuggestions, editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter and editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters settings.

[How to disable IntelliSense in VS Code for Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832753/how-to-disable-intellisense-in-vs-code-for-markdown)

Comment: This does not resolve my issue. Please read question carefully. i don't want to disable it. i want it to give me js instead of typescript(es6).