# VSCode, Asciidoc, how to disable syntax hint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, asciidoc

Using

- VSCode v1.54.4
- asciidoctor.asciidoctor-vscode extension v2.8.8
- Ubuntu 20.04.2

Whenever I type a colon `:` in the body text, there is an intellisense popup which comes up. As I rarely use attributes, I must dismiss that syntax hint by ESC. But from time to time, I accidentally insert the syntax hint and had to manually delete all the inserted characters.

Is there anyway to disable this syntax hint and ONLY for Asciidoc documents (`*.adoc`)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832753/how-to-disable-intellisense-in-vs-code-for-markdown) is for Markdown documents, but describes the suggestion options that are available.

Based on your question, you might consider adjusting the "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter" item, so that accidental insertions of suggestions happens less frequently.

Comment: Works perfect. In fact, I had already applied the tricks in the link you suggested. But didn't work b/c I don't know which key to set. Here is what I had: `"[asciidoc]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false,
    "editor.suggest.showValues": false
  }
`

Comment: The setting you suggested ` "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"` does indeed prevent the accidental insertion. I was trying a few other `editor.xxx` to completely disable that popup but don't know which one exactly.