# How can I disable `Log error to console` snippet in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Is there a way to disable the error snippet in Visual Studio Code, its very frustrating pressing tab after typing in `err` then it adds `console.error()`

I have disabled all extensions in Visual Studio Code

Comment: Can you provide more context about this problem? (Like: where is this setting in Visual Studio Code )

Comment: why do you press `Enter` or `Tab` after `err`? You can disable one of these key to insert a snippet. If you type `err<space>` you don't get a snippet

Comment: @Luuk that's the thing, I don't know where this setting or snippet is set. I'd like to know where it is set and how to disable it.

Comment: @rioV8 I press `tab` after typing `err` because of intellisense. Its usually after using a try/catch statement like `catch(error)`, I start typing in `err` then as a reflex from using intellisense for long that I automatically press `tab`

Comment: @AlexW: The context that I was asking about is that you do get this snippet, when using Visual Studio Code, when editing a Javascript file.

Comment: You can disable the snippets (a.k.a. intellisense) completely per filetype (see: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832753/how-to-disable-intellisense-in-vs-code-for-markdown) which explains how to do that for MarkDown). I do not think you can disable just 1 on the intellisense things....   (TL/DR): Complete docs for intellisense are here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense