# How to disable annoying highlight in Vs Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, settings

As the title says, i just want to know how to disable this annoying highlight in vs code. I want to get a suggestion instantly when i type inside the parentheses but instead first i get an annoying highlight that it wont go out unless i press ESC key.

As you can see in the images, first the console.log() have a weird highlight, that prevents the suggestion to pop up when i type the name of the variable or even functions.

[image: Here is the highlight when i try to type the variable x inside console.log (no suggestion is showing) unless i press Esc key or change to another tab]

[image: Here is when i press ESC key and get rid of the highlight, i press x and the suggestion will work instantly]

[image]

[image]

Comment: (This is one reason I stopped using VS Code and went back to Sublime)

Comment: I know how it feels, its super annoying to press ESC key every single time or the suggestions wont show up. I think there should be an option to disable that highlight but dont know where to start or where should be located.

Comment: I think it was called "quick suggestions" or "intellisense" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832753/how-to-disable-intellisense-in-vs-code-for-markdown

Comment: it is a Unicode highlight

Comment: Thanks, tried that but didnt work, i figured it out that if i type for example, console.log() all by myself that weird highlight isnt showing up, only shows when for example im typing console.  and then select a suggestion from intellisense.

Comment: The bracket highlighting can be disabled with the `Editor: Match Brackets` command.

Comment: Finally i managed to get rid of the weird highlight. I disabled "Editor>Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions" and now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

Look on VsCode settings "Editor>Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions" disable and done.

Comment: That doesn't turn off the highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer for anyone that found this as annoying as I did. The setting below should be changed to false, the default is true.

```json
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false
```

The other setting can be changed in Editor: Quick Suggestions.

`Other` should be set to on (which I believe is the default), and `strings` should be set to `on`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for. Paste this in your settings.json.

```json
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ${0} for the final placeholder to not auto-highlight the code.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a custom color for this highlighting feature. So just pass in the color of your current editor background to make it go away.

Here it is set to red:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.snippetTabstopHighlightBackground": "#ff0000"
}
```