# Disable snippet highlighting in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, syntax-highlighting

I would like to disable highlighting of texts inside snippet like

[image]

I have searched for this question everywhere and I have found only one [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70561040/how-to-disable-annoying-highlight-in-vs-code)
but the accepted solution doesn't work for me. I know I can change the highlight colour but I would prefer if there are no highlights at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to highlight what are you writing after using a snippet, you just have to place your cursor at the position you want to. Highight means something like "variable" so you can type in one place and your snippet will fill the other parts.

For example, my super simple snippet:

```json
"console.log": {
    "scope": "typescript, typescriptreact",
    "prefix": ["cl", "clo", "clog"],
    "body": ["console.log($0)"],
    "description": "Use Translation hook"
  },
```

`$0` - this places your cursor exactly at that position, without any highlighting.