# Disable hover text in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Every time I hover over a variable, or anything, I get a description. How do I disable this?

Comment: to disable hover, read <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/41115383/14901922" >thread</a>

Comment: You want to disable intellisense : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832753/how-to-disable-intellisense-in-vs-code-for-markdown